# Better way to check a String?

Tags: java, android

I have a code that check a string for space,comma and etc. Well since 
I will deal a scenario where my app will going to check, lets say thousand of string with a max length of 15 and a minimum length of 14. I am worried if it will affect the performance since it is in android. Check the code i used..

```
private final static char[] undefinedChars = {' ','/','.','<','>','*','!'};

    public static boolean checkMessage(String message){

    if (message == null)
        return false;

    char[] _message = message.toCharArray();

    for (char c : _message) {
         for (int i = 0;i > undefinedChars.length;i++)
                if (c == undefinedChars[i])
                    return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Is this correct? or there is a way to improve it?

Comment: Why not try it on an Android with 1000 15-character strings and see if it meets your performance requirements? Worst case test would be if no strings contained those characters. 1000x `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"` would do the trick, for example.

Comment: The answer to this question depends partially on how old of a phone you are trying to target as well. There are some pretty low-end devices out there, although I agree with Jason that this amount of data should be quite manageable.

Comment: @nj_15 you can also consider using a `Set` collection for your `undefinedChars` You could check each character of your String to see if it is contained in your Set. I will provide code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a change that you could make that *might* make a little difference:

Change

```
    char[] _message = message.toCharArray();
    for (char c : _message) {
```

to

```
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        char c = message.charAt(i);
```

However, I doubt that it will be significant.

Replacing the inner loop with a `switch` is more likely to be fruitful, though it depends on what the JIT compiler does with the code.  (And a switch will only works if the set of undefined characters can be hard-wired into the switch statement as compile-time constants.)

---

> I am worried if it will affect the performance since it is in android.

Don't "worry".  Approach the problem scientifically.

1. Implement the code and then benchmark it.
2. If the *measured* performance is a concern, then:

   1. profile the code
   2. look at hotspots, and identify *possible* improvements
   3. implement and test possible improvement
   4. rerun the benchmark to see if the improvement actually made any difference
   5. repeat ... until performance is good enough or you run out of options.

---

The other thing to note is that the same code could well perform differently across different Android platforms.  The quality of JIT compilers has (apparently) improved markedly in more recent releases.

I would argue that it is a bad idea to "bend" your code just to get it to run well on old phones.  The chances are that the user will upgrade their hardware soon anyway ... and it is conceivable that your optimization for the old platform actually makes your code slower on a new platform ... 'cos your hand-optimizations have made the code too tricky for the JIT compiler's optimizer to deal with.

This is also an argument for NOT trying to make your code go "as fast as possible" ...

Comment: eclipse doesn't let me use an enhanced for loop on on a string, is that what u meant?

Comment: yeah.. you need to change it tochararray first.. i try it gives me an error

Comment: Sorry.  My mistake.  That means that that "optimization" won't achieve anything at all.  Updated.  But as I said, this is marginal at best.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I see a bug there.

```
for (int i = 0;i > undefinedChars.length;i++)
```

that I think you meant

```
for (int i = 0;i < undefinedChars.length;i++)
```

instead?

Anyway it seems that your algorithm runs in O(m*n) where m is the length of message and n is the length of undefined chars(in this case fixed size, 15). Therefore it should be efficient in run-time analysis perspective.

I would profile the scenario first then decide how to improve it, that you could've sorted the message upfront somewhere then you can only check for either 1st char or the last char of the string, but as I said, only if that's been sorted elsewhere.

Or maybe think of parallelizing the routine. It should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Without using memory, you're about as fast as you can get.  You can trade memory for performance.  For example, you can put the characters you want to check into a HashMap.  Then you can loop over the string you're checking, and check if each index is in that map or not.  If the number of characters you want to check for is small, this will be less efficient.  If the number is big, it will be more efficient (Technically this algorithm is O(n) instead of O(n*m), but if m is small then the constants you're usually taught to ignore will matter).

Another way is to use an array of booleans, with each possible character in the string mapping to an index in that array.  Set only the characters you care about to true (and save that array).  Then you can avoid the hash calculation above, but at the cost of a lot of memory.

Really, your original algorithm is likely good enough.  But these (especially the hash map) are things you can consider if needed.

Comment: switch statement is actually the same as your boolean idea, compiler turns a switch into an internal function array of jmpTo points.  It really takes no memory (he's only ruling out 7 cases of nearby numbers).   HashIdea i fear would be pretty slow, though, with a binary search on each number.

Comment: A hash is only a binary search if implemented as a tree.  I believe a HashMap is an actual hash table, which is O(1), although the has itself will take time.  Hard coded if statements/switch is indeed faster, although I'm not sure a switch would optimize to a jump table due to the relative sparseness of that table.  I don't know enough about how Dalvik optimizes to say for sure though.

Comment: +1 good point, can't guarantee switch gets turned into a jmp table (forgot about that).  If it isn't, it becomes something that requires a binary search as well.  The compiler chooses which to emphasize (speed or memory), and we never see.  Guess I if I were doing this, I'd implement your boolean idea to be sure, since we want speed here, and a few 100 booleans on the heap isn't anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular expression. I find it very clean and it should not hurt your performance.

```
public static boolean checkMessage(String message)
{
    if (message == null)
        return false;

    String regex = " |\\.|/|<|>|\\*|!";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(message);
    if (matcher.find())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: ITs cleaner to read, but it will definitely effect performance-  regular expressions are moderately expensive, even when precompiled.

Answer (score 0):

For symmetry and possibly some compiler optimization, why not use a for-each style loop for both loops. As an additional benefit, you wouldn't risk a typo like the one pointed out by glaze. Your code would then become:

```
private final static char[] undefinedChars = {' ','/','.','<','>','*','!'};

public static boolean checkMessage(String message){

if (message == null)
    return false;

char[] _message = message.toCharArray();

for (char c : _message) {
     for (for u : undefinedChars)
            if (c == u)
                return true;
}

return false;
```

}

An additional optimization would be to order the characters in undefinedChars in the order most likely to occur. That way you'll bail-out as quick as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Set` to hold your `undefinedChars`

```
Set<Character> undefinedChars = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(new Character(' ') ,new Character('/'),new Character('.')));

public boolean hasUndefinedChar(String str) {
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char iChar = str.charAt(i);
    Character charWrapper = new Character(iChar);
    if (undefinedChars.contains(charWrapper)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This method is `O(n)` time efficient and does not sufficiently affect space complexity. The contains calls to the `Set` are `O(1)` operations and you make `n` of these contains calls in the worst case.